# How to limit RAM usage while batch training in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, training-data

I am training a *deep neural network* with a *large image dataset* in mini-batches of size 40. My dataset is in `.mat` format (which I can easily change to any other format e.g. `.npy` format if necessitates) and before training, loaded as a 4-D `numpy` array. My problem is that while training, cpu-RAM (not GPU RAM) is very quickly exhausting and starts using almost half of my Swap memory.

My training code has the following pattern:

```
batch_size = 40
...
with h5py.File('traindata.mat', 'r') as _data:
    train_imgs = np.array(_data['train_imgs'])

# I can replace above with below loading, if necessary
# train_imgs = np.load('traindata.npy')

...

shape_4d = train_imgs.shape 
for epoch_i in range(max_epochs):
    for iter in range(shape_4d[0] // batch_size):
        y_ = train_imgs[iter*batch_size:(iter+1)*batch_size]
        ...
        ...
```

This seems like the initial loading of the full training data is itself becoming the bottle-neck (taking over 12 GB cpu RAM before I abort).

What is the best efficient way to tackle this bottle-neck?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) Buy more RAM, (2) prepare a numpy-memmap-based numpy array and slice on demand or (3) do the same using hdf5. The latter two might need some care in terms of epoch-wise shuffling (you don't want random-access into out-of-memory data as OS-caching won't work nicely then). And of course: check out tf's API on how to incorporate this API-wise.

Comment: @sascha: Are you saying that (2) or (3) is more efficient than using `tfrecord`s?

Comment: I don't know tf much and can't say anything about that. But slicing memmaps or hdf5 can produce a view (at least non-fancy slices), so no copying. So in theory you can get away of only holding the current batch in your memory all the time (i warned about underlying caching and random-access). Your code-example on the other hand does create a complete array-copy (at least i would assume that). In general i'm only pointing to some ideas or things you should check out (slicing hdf5). If that will work out for your case, i'm afraid, you have to check yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Loading a big dataset in memory is not a good idea. I suggest you to use something different for loading the datasets, take a look to the dataset API in TensorFlow: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets

You might need to convert your data into other format, but if you have a CSV or TXT file with a example per line you can use `TextLineDataset` and feed the model with it:

```py
filenames = ["/var/data/file1.txt", "/var/data/file2.txt"]
dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(filenames)

def _parse_py_fun(text_line):
    ... your custom code here, return np arrays

def _map_fun(text_line):
    result = tf.py_func(_parse_py_fun, [text_line], [tf.uint8])
    ... other tensorlow code here
    return result

dataset = dataset.map(_map_fun)
dataset = dataset.batch(4)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
input_data_of_your_model = iterator.get_next()

output = build_model_fn(input_data_of_your_model)

sess.run([output]) # the input was assigned directly when creating the model
```